# Flat shading in graphics pipeline

Tags: graphics, 3d, lighting

I have been asked to analyze Flat shading model for 3d lighting and to "discuss how it integrate in the graphics pipeline".

[image]

Since flat shading is applied once per face, I was thinking the right place where light is computed is the phase of fragments computation. However I may also be totally wrong...

Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That diagram isn't particularly readable. This one is much, much easier on the eyes:

[image]

... and also correctly places the stage at which normals are interpolated: before the fragment shader or raster operations, which finalizes the fragments. I think in terms of your diagram, this is the area labelled 'set-up'.

For flat shading, normals are not interpolated across the surface of the polygon. However, they will still be passed through the interpolation stage so that the appropriate normal for a fragment can be determined, where more than one may be available. So, the normals are determined in the rasterization and interpolation however the actual colouring and lighting are determined by the fragment shader. This is the modern approach: In a fixed pipeline (without a fragment shader), it would all be done by the rasterizer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May you explain further what do you mean by  "they will still be passed through the interpolation stage so that the appropriate normal for a fragment can be determined, where more than one may be available"? How can there be more than one normal for the fragment?

Comment: @Saphrosit Normals are most usually provided per vertex, and then interpolated across the surface of the polygon. This is good if you were drawing a sphere but bad if you were drawing a cube, so flat shading should be used instead. However, a triangle has 3 points and thus, 3 different normals to choose from in a flat shading scenario: which one gets used must be determined and this is done in the interpolation stage.

Comment: Yes, you are describing Phong shading method, based on normal interpolation. For what I know, in flat shading normals are computed as `N = (v1-v0)x(v2-v0)` where `vi` are the vertices of the triangle and `x` denotes the cross-product. Does this computation take place in "Rasterization and interpolation" step replacing normal interpolation (according to the shading method adopted)?

Comment: @Saphrosit Yes, it would, so it could then be passed to the shader stage or used to compute fixed pipeline lighting. It would have to, because the pixel shader isn't inherently aware of the geometry it represents.

Comment: Ok, thank you. May you suggest some reference where I can get further informations? :)

Comment: @Saphrosit The [GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch28.html) series are worth a look, as are Jim Blinn's books, although Blinn's books are quite old now. Reading some of the [whitepapers](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf) and working backwards, rading and researching new material as you encounter it might be a good idea.